# Is there something like the Academy Awards for anime?

Tags: anime-history

I was wondering if there is an organization that hands out awards to anime in different categories. Something like the Academy Awards for movies in the US.

Or if not, maybe just an organization that publishes evaluations of anime based on various criteria that can be used for comparison.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two I could find:

> [Tokyo Anime Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Anime_Award):  The Tokyo Anime Award started from 2002, but was named in 2005. The
>   first, second and third awards were only named simply
>   'Competition'.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Anime_Award) The award ceremony was held at the Tokyo
>   International Anime Fair (TAF) until 2013. In 2014, after the merger
>   of Tokyo International Anime Fair with Anime Contents Expo and
>   formation of AnimeJapan convention, Tokyo Anime Award started as a
>   separate festival called Tokyo Anime Award Festival (TAAF).

As per @senshin's input: They do consider western animation as anime too for the Awards. [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(2006_film)) was the winner of Open Entries/Competition Grand Prize in 2007 being the first non-asian entry[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Anime_Award#Open_Entries_.2F_Competition_Grand_Prize).

They also have a specific website on it: http://animefestival.jp/en

There is one more from America:

> [American Anime Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Anime_Awards): The American Anime Awards were a series of awards designed to
>   **recognize excellence in the release of anime and manga in North
>   America.**
>
> The first and, as of 2015, only annual American Anime Awards balloting
>   was supervised by Milton Griepp of industry website ICv2. The first
>   gala awards presentation was hosted in New York City on February 24,
>   2007 at New York Comic Con. The hosts of the evening were eight
>   actresses from the anime production company ADV Films: Christine
>   Auten, Shelley Calene-Black, Jessica Boone, Luci Christian, Alice
>   Fulks, Hilary Haag, Taylor Hannah and Serena Varghese. A streaming
>   version of the one hour awards ceremony can be seen on IGN.com. The
>   awards were later broadcast on the Anime Network.

Comment: The American Anime Awards are not really comparable. The Tokyo Anime Awards are comparable, though it should be noted that it covers everything that the Japanese people regard as "anime", which includes western animation like Disney/Pixar stuff.

Comment: @senshin it was not much clear from the source i gathered on the first read, will try to improve the answer in a bit. Thanks for the input